# Efficient way to fill 2d array in Python

Tags: python, performance, optimization, scipy, sparse-matrix

I have 3 arrays: array "words" of pairs ["id": "word"] by the length 5000000, array "ids" of unique ids by the length 13000 and array "dict" of unique words (dictionary) by the length 500000. This is my code:

```
matrix = sparse.lil_matrix((len(ids), len(dict)))
for i in words:
    matrix[id.index(i['id']), dict.index(i['word'])] += 1.0
```

But it works too slow (I haven't got a matrix after 15 hours of work). Are there any ideas to optimize my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all don't name your array `dict`, it is confusing as well as hides the built-in type `dict`.

The problem here is that you're doing everything in quadratic time, so convert your arrays `dict` and `id` to a dictionary first where each `word` or `id` point to its index.

```
matrix = sparse.lil_matrix((len(ids), len(dict)))
dict_from_dict = {word: ind for ind, word in enumerate(dict)}
dict_from_id = {id: ind for ind, id in enumerate(id)}
for i in words:
    matrix[dict_from_id[i['id']], dict_from_dict[i['word']] += 1.0
```